# Numpy Where with more than 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

Good Morning,

I have the following a dataframe with two columns of integers and a Series (diff) computed as:

```
diff = (df["col_1"] - df["col_2"]) / (df["col_2"])
```

I would like to create a column of the dataframe whose values are:

- equal to 0, if (diff >= 0) & (diff <= 0.35)
- equal to 1, if (diff > 0.35)
- equal to 2, if (diff < 0) & (diff  >= - 0.35)
- equal to 3, if (diff < - 0.35)

I tried with:

```
df["Class"] = np.where( (diff >= 0) &  (diff <= 0.35), 0, 
np.where( (diff > 0.35), 1, 
np.where( (diff  < 0) & (diff >=  - 0.35) ), 2, 
np.where( ((diff <  - 0.35), 3) )))
```

But it reports the following error:

```
SystemError: <built-in function where> returned a result with an error set
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to specify conditions and values separately.

```
s = (df['col_1'] / df['col_2']) - 1

conditions = [s.between(0, 0.35), s > 0.35, s.between(-0.35, 0), s < -0.35]
values = [0, 1, 2, 3]

df['Class'] = np.select(conditions, values, np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also simply use [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
diff_classes = [-0.35,0,0.35]
def getClass(x):
    return len(diff_classes)-np.searchsorted(diff_classes,x)

df["class"]=diff.apply(getClass)
```

`searchsorted` will give you the index of `x` in the `diff_classes` list, which you then substract from 3 to get your desired result.

**edit**: A little bit less readable, but it also works in one line:

```
df["class"] = diff.apply(lambda x: 3-np.searchsorted([-0.35,0,0.35],x))
```